# Is There a Good Companion for Theory of Moral Sentiments

Tags: reference-request, adam-smith

I am reading "The Theory of Moral Sentiments" by Adam Smith. There's a lot of technical, and/or dated language. Is there a good companion to read this with?

Comment: Vernon Smith recently released something (or will soon) with Bart Wilson dealing with that text.

Comment: @123: I think you may be referring to [*Humanomics*](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/humanomics/1B4064A206BD99DB36E794B53ADF8BB4) (2019) by Vernon Smith and Bart Wilson. (I'm not sure though that it's the sort of book that Jay is looking for.)

Comment: Maybe not. However, it does include the phrase "moral sentiments [...] for the twenty-first century..." in its description :) so maybe so?

Comment: Ah, Vern and I go way back. I'll just ask him for a copy when we golf next week.